# Unity android build screen freeze

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So, my game in the windows build works perfectly but it freezes in my android build when my gamescene is finally loaded. It's a network game so I can see my android player moving, it's just that the screen it's permanently frozen. I have no errors in console and in one of my build I managed to get this: not sure if it helps, not sure what to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJJKR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Vulkan API for Android - instead of GLES:
 https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GraphicsAPIs.html